# Alternative for CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use rspec, devise and cancan at the moment. To be honest, I find cancan to be very confusing and I am encountering a lot difficulties in picking it up and using it effectively. The docs are not very in depth making this extremely difficult for me to debug (check my past questions).

Is there an alternative to CanCan that's also easily integratable in the other tools I am using?

Answer (score 35):

As of early 2014, **[Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)** is a popular alternative to CanCan (and the successor CanCanCan). Pundit matches each controller with a policy object. Unlike CanCan, there's no central rule file for all access control. It's simpler than CanCan. There's an example app from the [RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.io/) project:

> **[Rails Pundit Example](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit)**

I've also written a tutorial on [Rails Authorization with Pundit](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-devise-pundit/).

Another alternative is the **[Authority gem](https://github.com/nathanl/authority)** from Nathan Long. All your rules logic goes in Ruby classes called "authorizers" that are associated with models.

Comment: Thanks! I also try to look out for SO questions tagged `authority-gem`.

Comment: +1 for your support.. Really appreciate your work thanks...!!

Comment: Also I found "cancancan" and "the role" gems active and useful...!!!

Comment: I came here because I am looking to upgrade to Rails 4, and find a Rails 4 compatible authorization system that can substitute for cancan and integrate with devise. Is Pundit the right tool for this?

Comment: Pundit is a good choice for integration with Rails 4.1 and Devise. See the example app referenced above.

Comment: Pundit absolutely rocks!

Answer (score 7):

Some guys are continuing the development of cancan. Check it out:

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Answer (score 4):

For the same reason i've done this: http://mcasimir.github.com/checkin/.

**Checkin** is an authorization gem that is independent from the role/authentication library you use.

You can express even complex rules rather simply with a declarative/cascading permissions DSL.

I found it very handy. The debug is also supported via the `explain` method that will log the authorization process on every request.

Here are some of the features:

- Handy DSL to define roles and permissions with a declarative approach
- Check authorization for CRUD operations automatically
- Standard way to rescue from Authorization errors
- Authorization subject decoupled from model (compatible with any autentication system)
- Role-based authorization decoupled from role system (compatible with any role
  system)
- Decorator for current_user and other subject objects
- Scoped authorization rules
- Cascading authorization rules
- Simple: even complex authorization behaviour is understandable at glimpse and
  easily predictable
- Support for controller based mass assignment protection

Here is a very simple example of the DSL:

```
class UserSubject < Checkin::Subject

      role :guest, :alias => :anonymous do
          !subject_model
      end

      role :logged_in, :alias => [:connected] do
          !!subject_model
      end

      role :owner, :require => [:logged_in], :method => :own do |object|
          object && ( object.respond_to?(:author) && ( subject_model == object.author ) ) ||  ( object.respond_to?(:owner) && ( subject_model == object.owner ) )
      end

      role :administrator, :require => :logged_in, :alias => :admin do
          subject_model.has_role?(:administrator)
      end

      #
      # Permissions
      #

      permissions :for => :comments do
        allow :administrators
        allow :logged_in, :to => [:create]
        deny
      end

      # Admin

      scope :admin do
        permissions do
          allow :administrators
          allow :owners,  :to => [:edit, :update]
          deny
        end
      end

end
```

Checking roles and permissions:

```
subject = UserSubject.new(User.first, :scope => :admin)
subject.logged_in?
subject.guest?
subject.own?(Post.first)
subject.can_edit?(Post.first)
```

I apologize for being so wordy.

Answer (score 3):

I found https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization to be rather complete. And it's logical to use.

Comment: there is a Railscast available too

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like Pundit may be coming up strong. It has a less 'magic', more straightforward approach.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: simply best..Pundit...

Answer (score 2):

I am currently exploring [Heimdallr](https://github.com/roundlake/heimdallr). The one feature it has that most of these cancan alternatives don't are restricted scopes for index actions.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to check out this "ultra lite authorization library" - [six](https://github.com/randx/six)

Comment: This looks _nice_, and it seems to be maintained regularly unlike CanCan which hasn't been updated in months! How's Rails 3.1 compatibility?

Comment: @Matheus Moreira It is a new gem released 3-4 weeks back. Has a lot less features than caccan. Code base is just one file actually. There shouldn't be any problems with rails 3.1 as it doesn't inject any of its magic to rails.

Comment: CanCan has been giving me `method missing` errors ever since I migrated to Rails 3.1, so I decided to replace it, but I still haven't finished adapting my software. I think it could enjoy better integration with Rails in particular, but maybe that would be better left to a separate Gem, like `six-rails`.

Comment: @Matheus Moreira Yous might want to take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1175760)

Answer (score 1):

Check [TheRole](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role) gem. very interesting alternative for cancan

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Action Access](//github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access), it's much simpler and straightforward, has seamless integration with Rails and it's very lightweight. It boils down to this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  let :admin, :all
  let :user, [:index, :show]

  # ...
end
```

This will automatically lock the controller, allowing admins to access every action, users only to show or index articles and anyone else will be rejected and redirected with an alert.

If you need more control, you can use `not_authorized!` inside actions to check and reject access.

This makes controllers to be self contained, everything related to the controller is within the controller. This also makes it very modular and avoids leaving forgotten trash anywhere else when you refactor.

It's completely **independent** of the authentication system and it can work without `User` models or predefined roles. All you need is to set the clearance level for the current request:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_clearance_level
    session[:role] || :guest
  end
end
```

You may return whatever your app requires, like `current_user.role` for example.

It also bundles a set of handy model additions that allow to extend user models and do things like:

```
<% if current_user.can? :edit, :article %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit article', edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

Here `:article` refers to `ArticlesController`, so the link will only be displayed if the current user is authorized to access the `edit` action in `ArticlesController`. It supports **namespaces** too.

It allows to lock controllers by default, customize the redirection path and the alert message, etc. Checkout the [documentation](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/action_access#action-access) for more.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Consul](https://github.com/makandra/consul).

You create a `Power` class with methods that return only those objects the user has access to, instead of loading objects and check permissions on them. [Talk by the author](http://bizarre-authorization.talks.makandra.com).